# xPath Namemapping for several dropdowns

Tags: excel, google-chrome, ms-word

I have a button that is dynamic in several webscreens using TestComplete.

I have a buttonKeep object that is successfully implemented in the first screen it goes through the first screen and selects a Word and Excel document copies data up and then I paste it to the website

//div[(contains(@style,'display: block'))]//button[@id='Keep']

OR //div[not(contains(@style,"display:none'))]//button[contains(@class, 'fr-keep-word')]

OR //button[contains(@class, 'fr-keep-word')]

OR //div[2]/div/div/button[2]

OR //div[contains(@style,'display: block')]

Now I will select a screen that will move me on to a series of dropdowns where I will do the same thing in one of the drop downs. The system wants to add a different buttonKeep object everytime I run the test rather than recognized that the item had been mapped correctly earlier. Or even when I selected the first time I run the test.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this issue is due to a dynamic element in the page object. With the page objects being different, that cause the same object to be mapped again.

I would recommend investigating the page objects, and if they are the same page, but with a dynamic section, add wildcard values to account for the dynamic nodes.

To make mapping settings independent of dynamic changes in web page URLs, you can use the asterisk (*) wildcard in place of the values -- http://www.example.com/index.asp?act=12312&sid=, or in place of the entire query string -- http://www.example.com/index.asp*.